iOS FairPlay error -42803 for offline playback
The FairPlay license we configured is correctly sharing the content key required for offline playback.
But the problem is that - offline playback works once and fails afterwords.
AVPlayer Error:

Code: -42803, domain: CoreMediaErrorDomain, description: The operation
couldn’t be completed. (CoreMediaErrorDomain error -42803.),
underlyingErrors: []

Error Code -42803 represents - Offline key is invalid.
So I'm not sure who decides the validity of content key or how this is valid for the first playback and fails later on. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Only the DRM provider can help in such a situation as they only have request/response details.
Solution:

Request/Response was correct, I was getting content key but it was invalid.
Problem was with Apple's API used to manage the DRM, currently I was trying all this with AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate
When upgraded DRM protocol to AVContentKeySessionDelegate then everything is working as expected.

Not sure if this is because DRM provider only supports AVContentKeySessionDelegate but this solution worked for us.

I'm already using AVContentKeySessions and just started to use AVPersistableContentKeyRequests and get the same behaviour: I first get a key from the key server, make it persistable and store it. At a next playback launch (after relaunching the app), I get this error but for one specific content key identifier.
